# Could not resolve host: gogs-repo

Tags: docker

I have a running container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3825fa57b1ae        repo:0.1.0          "/app/gogs/docker/st…"   29 minutes ago      Up 29 minutes       22/tcp, 3000/tcp    gogs-repo
```

and tried to curl it from another container as follows:

```
docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.69.1 -L -v http://gogs-repo:3000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: gogs-repo
```

I've started the `gogs-repo` container as follows:

```
docker run --rm --name gogs-repo repo:0.1.0
usermod: no changes
Apr 26 10:37:56 syslogd started: BusyBox v1.31.1
2020/04/26 10:37:56 [TRACE] Log mode: File (Info)
Apr 26 10:37:57 sshd[36]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Apr 26 10:37:57 sshd[36]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

and as you can see, it is up and running. Why curl can the reach `http://gogs-repo:3000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your service is running on port 3000 inside container gogs-repo(because I am not sure after looking at the container logs), you should make the following changes in the existing setup.

First thing first. The two containers - **gogs-repo** and **another container** (from where you are trying to access the service) are not connected to each other. Hence the host `gogs-repo` is not resolved.

To fix this, you need to run both the containers in single network.

You can perform the following steps to achieve the desired result.

- Create a private bridge network.

  ```
  docker network create --driver bridge mynetwork
  ```
- Now start your application containers along with the `--network mynetwork` added to your docker run command.
- Finally, the updated docker run command looks like the following:

  ```
  docker run --network mynetwork --rm --name gogs-repo repo:0.1.0

  docker run --rm curlimages/curl:7.69.1 -L -v http://gogs-repo:3000
  ```

With the following changes, you are good to access `http://gogs-repo:3000`

[Good read](https://blog.csainty.com/2016/07/connecting-docker-containers.html)

Here is one more approach ([easy but not recommended](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)) to achieve the desired result.

**Using Docker links**

As mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links):

> Links allow containers to discover each other and securely transfer information about one container to another container. When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container.

We can link the container from which we want to access the service using `--link` argument.

```
docker run --link gogs-repo:gogs-repo --rm curlimages/curl:7.69.1 -L -v http://gogs-repo:3000
```

What `--link` does is that it creates a secure tunnel between the containers that don’t need to expose any ports externally on the container.

Comment: Why do I need to expose port 3000 on `gogs-repo`?